# Web Extension : How do I use "browser_style = true"?

Tags: css, firefox-addon-webextensions

When writing a Firefox web extension it's possible to use a default css for browser or page actions so that they are styled like other browser UI components. It's done by inserting:

```
"browser_style": true
```

in the extension manifest. Styles like `panel-section-footer-button` become available.

My question: How can you know how to use the default styles, there doesn't seem to be an official source or description of them?

---

Related:

- The css in built-in resource `chrome://browser/content/extension.css`.
- This [popup example](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/blob/master/latest-download/popup/latest_download.html) on Mozilla site, which uses some default styles..

Comment: [The new MDN web docs explain that in more detail.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Browser_styles)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `"browser_style": true` results in the `chrome://browser/content/extension.css` file [being applied to your HTML](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/955840bfd3c20eb24dd5a01be27bdc55c489a285/browser/components/extensions/ext-utils.js#62) ([on OSX](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/955840bfd3c20eb24dd5a01be27bdc55c489a285/browser/components/extensions/ext-utils.js#68) `chrome://browser/content/extension-mac.css` is applied instead).

Mozilla has a [Style Guide](https://firefoxux.github.io/StyleGuide/#/introduction) which you can peruse to see how various elements and classes are used. The link to this Style Guide is in the [`browser_style` entry within the "Syntax" section of the `browser_action` documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/browser_action#Syntax). A similar link is in the same location on the [`page_action` MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/page_action#Syntax). Personally, I would find it more appropriate for the information contained in the Style Guide to be hosted directly on MDN rather than on `firefoxux.github.io`.

If you are just interested in the elements and classes, you can find examples under the [Components section](https://firefoxux.github.io/StyleGuide/#/controls).

Note: Under [some conditions](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/955840bfd3c20eb24dd5a01be27bdc55c489a285/browser/components/extensions/ext-browserAction.js#203), Firefox also [attempts to apply](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/955840bfd3c20eb24dd5a01be27bdc55c489a285/browser/components/extensions/ext-utils.js#190) `chrome://browser/content/extension-win-panel.css` or `chrome://browser/content/extension-mac-panel.css` neither of which exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks like this guide location is a secret transmitted between generations of initiates, impossible to find by your own :-) For others looking for the same information, a good entry point is [this one](https://firefoxux.github.io/StyleGuide/#/controls). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @mins, I'm glad I was able to help. Yeah, it took me a bit to notice the link to the Style Guide. Until I found it, I had been figuring I was going to be looking through the source code to see what was being done. So, at least we are a bit better off than we would be without it. The information really should be directly on MDN, where we search for primary information related to Firefox add-ons.

Comment: @Fully agreed, and... it took time to me also and started thinking I was going to read only generalities, in addition for some reason the table of contents links are sometimes not working! If I could upvote twice, I would!