# [] Loop checking for button Chrome Extension not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> Hi guys, I am trying to create a chrome extension that once I click the chrome extension, the script will start and will loop check every 1 millisecond for a button with the **id** "product-addtocart-button". So, once the loop finds the button it needs to be clicked right away.

I guess if it's necessary, the site is Adidas.ae and once a new shoe comes out there will be a countdown to the shoe being available, and once the countdown is over the button add to card will be available to click, and I need to click that right away.

--

I took in @Barmar's suggestion and changed the id"product-addtocard-button" to a variable and using it in the function parameters. I also took away the braces from the function after "tab.id".

My original code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
function waitForElementToDisplay(#product-addtocart-button, 10) {
        if(document.querySelector(#product-addtocart-button)!=null) {
            alert("document.getElementById('product-addtocart-button').click()")
            return;
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(function() {
                waitForElementToDisplay(#product-addtocart-button, 10);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

        });
});
```

The updated code:

```
var button = document.getElementById("product-addtocart-button");
var time = 10;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) 
    {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,

        function waitForElementToDisplay(button, time) {
                if(document.querySelector(button)!=null) 
                {
                    code: "document.getElementById(button).click();"
                    return;
                }
                else 
                {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        waitForElementToDisplay(button, time);
                    }, time);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Note: This is an extension to this question: [Why is my Javascript Chrome extension code not working? (Loop check for button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291947/why-is-my-javascript-chrome-extension-code-not-working-loop-check-for-button). I have taken in the suggestions and need a little more help, therefore am posting my updated code.

The problem with the extension is when it is clicked nothing is happening. Any help?

Comment: you have syntax errors. look closely how the callback should be defined. question can get closed as typo.

Comment: Without the error messages from the console (specifically, ones related to syntax), we can't do much with "nothing is happening."

Comment: @ssube I have provided the error messages here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303653/chrome-extension-loop-check-for-button-errors

Comment: Thanks everyone for downvoting and marking as off-topic... Hope you feel better about yourselves you heroes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [specifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), you have to invoke executeScript like:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{code:"yourCodePackedIntoOneString"});`

or

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"yourCodeFile.js"});`

but you are calling:

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{function()etc...});`.

Try this:

Have one file called **myWaitingLoop.js**:

```
function waitForElementToDisplay(){
    var button = document.querySelector("#product-addtocart-button");
    if (button){
        button.click();
    } else {
        setTimeout(waitForElementToDisplay,100);
    }
}  
waitForElementToDisplay();
```

and then, in your background.js script:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"myWaitingLoop.js"});
});
```

Comment: You are a legend man!!! Works exactly how I want to. I kept posting because I was scared nobody would see the question, based on I am in different time regioun (United arab emirates) and time difference in America nobody would see. thank you very much from Dubai :)

Comment: And still someone downvoted it... :(